# PostgreSQL installation on a Synology DiskStation (DS216j) & pgAdminIII

Tags: ssh, postgresql, synology

I have a local postgreSQL database installed on my linux computer.
I would like run this database on a NAS Synology DiskStation (DS216j) instead.

I followed this guideline until step 2:
http://iamsensoria.com/post/130235198606/postgres-on-synology
(I am able to create the database and the user)
But i am not able to do the step3.

I am trying to connect to the database with pgAdminIII but i get an error saying:

"he server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Oppkobling nektes Is the server running on host "192.168.0.16" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
If you encounter this message, please check if the server you're trying to contact is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port. Test if you have network connectivity from your client to the server host using ping or equivalent tools. Is your network / VPN / SSH tunnel / firewall configured correctly? 
For security reasons, PostgreSQL does not listen on all available IP addresses on the server machine initially. In order to access the server over the network, you need to enable listening on the address first. 
For PostgreSQL servers starting with version 8.0, this is controlled using the "listen_addresses" parameter in the postgresql.conf file. Here, you can enter a list of IP addresses the server should listen on, or simply use '*' to listen on all available IP addresses. For earlier servers (Version 7.3 or 7.4), you'll need to set the "tcpip_socket" parameter to 'true'. 
You can use the postgresql.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the postgresql.conf configuration file. After changing this file, you need to restart the server process to make the setting effective. 
If you double-checked your configuration but still get this error message, it's still unlikely that you encounter a fatal PostgreSQL misbehaviour. You probably have some low level network connectivity problems (e.g. firewall configuration). Please check this thoroughly before reporting a bug to the PostgreSQL community"

ps: I have opened the port 5432 on the sinology DS-216J.

Does anybody have gone through this before? Thanks in advance.

I also use this resources:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/423165/remotely-access-postgresql-database

------UPDATE 1----

```
ssh testuser@192.168.0.16
testuser@test:~$ sudo -s
sh-4.3# su - postgres
postgres@test:~$ psql
psql (9.3.14)
 Type "help" for help.
postgres=#  \l

---------------------------------

 download         | DownloadStation 
 mediaserver    | MediaIndex      
 mydb               | postgres       
 photo               | PhotoStation    
 postgres          | postgres       
 template0        | postgres        | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres   
                                                   postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1      | postgres        | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres   
                postgres=CTc/postgres
 usermydb       | postgres        | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 video_metadata | VideoStation    | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 

------------------------------------------------------------
postgres=# \c mydb
You are now connected to database "mydb" as user "postgres".
mydb=# SHOW hba_file;
          hba_file           
-----------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

    mydb=# sudo vim /etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf   // NOT WORKING
    mydb=# sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf // NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Sounds like you may need to configure your hba.conf to allow connections in

Comment: How can I check if the NAS (where i have previously started the db) is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port?

Comment: Use netstat: `netstat -tulnp | grep 5432`

Comment: I have logged in first with SSH from my pc to the NAS with an active user and I get --------------------------------:`testuser@test:~$ netstat -tulnp | grep 5432
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  `

Comment: Thats your problem! netstat shows that the PID is listening to your loopback address. Which is why you need to modify your hba conf to have the PID listen to not just listen to your loopback address.

Comment: You are correct. How can I check from my Pc, with the terminal, if the port 5432 on the NAS is actually listening then?

Comment: Use telnet... `telnet <host/IP> 5432` but if your doing this remotely, your not gonna be able to get connectivity, hence, modify your current configuration.

Comment: Ok yes, I have read something like this. The pc and the NAS are in the same network.

Comment: You still need to modify your configuration. Usually this issue occurs when running scripts/programs against your database.

Comment: I have solved in connection with this other post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378040/postgresql-port-open-on-nas-synology-diskstation-ds216j/378894#378894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Postgres is binding to your loopback address (127.0.0.1). This typically means that your database will not accept connections outside your loopback. It is evident based on your results running `netstat`.

The Solution:

You need to modify your pg_hba.conf file to allow outside connections (preferrably, your PC's IP address). Take  a look at the [following](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). I'm not 100% what version of Postgres your using but I can't imagine each version having vast differences between configuring your pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Ok so, to be able to modify this pg_hba.conf I will have to connect with telnet. After I modify the file my DB on the NAS can accept outside connection and eventually I will also be able to establish connection from gAdminIII. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. Your using telnet to test your connectivity from points A -> B. Once you modify the hba.conf and restart the daemon, you can use telnet to confirm you are able connect remotely. After which, you should be able to connect via pgAdmin

Comment: ok. I am understanding much more now. This is my first approach to linux. I am trying to migrate a local database which I made using pgAdminIII & LibreofficeBase to a NAS synology. If my pc has ip 192.168.0.11 and my NAS has 192.168.0.16 can I check the port using the command `telnet 192.168.0.16 5432` ? Because i tried that (also as a root), but i just get connection refused.

Comment: Yes that will work normally, but as i mentioned you need to change your configuration on the server side. The connection refused means postgres isnt accepting connections outside your localhost

Comment: When you say server side it means form the control panel of the Synology DiskStation (DS216j) ?

Comment: No. I mean your server that has 192.168.0.16. You need to SSH into that server and modify your pg_hba.conf and then restart postgress

Comment: I can connect from my pc to 192.168.0.16 (my NAS) via SSH and with a user that is an admin on the NAS. but from there i don't know what is the command that allow me to modify the file pg_hba.conf

Comment: I understand.. But this is stuff you need to learn and is elementary to using Linux. I would recommend learning the fundamentals first prior to installing and configuring a database server on Linux. Migrating a database to Linux w.o learning about it's features is counterproductive. The answer I posted is the reason why you can't connect to the database via pgadmin. But you need to learn how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the tips and to put me on the right way. I understand what you mean.

Comment: I have runned  this command to check where the file is located:   -------------                                                         `root@test:~# su - postgres
postgres@test:~$ psql
psql (9.3.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW hba_file;
          hba_file           
 /etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf`
(1 row)                                                        
The I run this to open the file but nothing happen.
`postgres=# sudo vim /etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: I do recommend modifying the configuration file as root

Comment: I tried but from root I cannot enter to sql for then lunch the other command to see the pg_hba.conf, because I get en error: `root@test:~# psql
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

Comment: Ah ok file perms issue - So I stand corrected on that one, use postgres user. But by nothing happening -- Im assuming that your unable to actually input any data in the file? If that is correct, again, you need to learn the fundamentals and review how vim works.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for pointing me in right direction. I have solved my problem and here i post my answer as resolution in case somebody else need it.